# Java : Class inheriting self

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I know this is pointless: I just find it funny and I want to inquire more about the mechanics of what happens when you create a class that inherits itself, resulting in a stack overflow crash. It's amazing that Java allows you to make such a construct to begin with.

I am just guessing, but is the JVM putting itself into an infinite loop trying to resolve the class before instancing it, or is it actually instancing multiple copies of the class endlessly?

I should have been more specific; I am using an inner class to derive from enclosing class.

```
 public class Outside {
    private int outsideValue;

    public class Inside extends Outside {
        private int insideValue;
        public Inside(int val) {
            insideValue = val;
        }
    }

    public Outside() {
        Inside o = new Inside(0);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outside o = new Outside();
    }
}
```

Comment: @TurtleToes So, what actually happened when you tried to do it?

Comment: what do you mean? I can't get any cyclic Inheritance, which version are you using? Inherit.java:1: cyclic inheritance involving First

Comment: Trying to inherit the class that is being declared causes a compile error (jdk 1.6 on Windows/Cygwin). What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Using an inner class to inherit from outer class

Comment: `javac` is not the only way to create a class file. You can also edit one to get a bogus class.

Comment: A thought problem for you; If all classes extend `Object` implicitly what does `Object` extend? ;)

Comment: see OP. I forgot to mention that I am extending an inner class with the enclosing class. it compiles, runs, and crashes with a stack overflow

Comment: @TurtleToes: Can you show a complete example? What exactly crashes?

Comment: from the Outside() constructor, create an instance of an Inside object.

Comment: I will update with the whole code that I have... 1 min

Comment: Okay, I have updated with a complete working code that will crash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that, since `Inside` extends `Outside`, it has an **implicit call to `super()`** which is the constructor of `Outside` (which in turn calls the constructor of `Inside`) and so it goes around.

The code you posted **is conceptually not different from the following program**:

```
class A {
    B b = new B();
}

class B extends A {
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A(); // Create an A...
                 //   ... which creates a B
                 //   ... which extends A thus implicitly creates an A
                 //   ... which creates a B
                 //   ...
    }
}
```

Comment: run the code I posted and you will get a stack overflow error

Comment: make another class and try to instance the Outside class.

Answer (score 2):

In its final form this problem has nothing to do with cyclic inheritance and inner classes. It's just an infinite recursion caused by unbound recursive constructor call. The same effect can be shown by the following simple example:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        new A();
    }
}
```

Note that this code is perfectly valid, since Java doesn't apply any restrictions on recursive calls.

In your case it's slightly more complicated due to inheritance, but if you recall that constructor of subclass implicitly call a constructor of superclass, it should be clear that these calls form infinite recursion.

Comment: Your example does not reflect on the fact that one class extends another. See my answer for an example slightly closer to the OPs.

Comment: I haven't slept in over 48 hours and I'm on my fifth giant can of red bull... seemed amazing to me at first

Answer (score 1):

Try in an IDE like eclipse, it wont allow you to do so. ie gives an error like this.

**Cycle detected: the type Test cannot extend/implement itself or one of its own member types**

Comment: But that's the IDE being smarter than the compiler (a good thing). What I'm surprised is that the java compiler allows such construct at all.

Answer (score 1):

Extending oneself generates an error of cyclic inheritance (which java doesn't allow). Your code sample does compile and is valid.

---

Due to [Vladimir Ivanov's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473070/vladimir-ivanov) persistence, I will fix my edit.

Your code throws a `StackOverflowError` because of the following.

```
Inside o = new Inside(0);
```

Since `Inside` extends `Outside`, `Inside` first calls the `super()` method implicitly (since you've not called it yourself). `Outside()` constructor initializes `Inside o` and the cycle runs again, until the stack is full and it overflow (there's too many `Inside` and `Outside` inside the heap stack).

Hope this helps especially Vladimir Ivanov.

Comment: this is not about cyclic inheritence(-1)

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov, the OP added code later, hence why I added the 2nd sentence.

Comment: Yep. And that's not my wish. FYI, SO doesn't allow you to change the vote, until the answer is edited.

Answer (score 1):

The java compiler is not going to enter into an infinite loop when trying to enter a cyclic inheritance chain. After all, every inheritance chain is a eventually finite graph (and, computationally speaking, with a very small number of nodes and edges.) More precisely, the inheritance graph from subclass A to (eventual) superclass Z must be a line (not the other way around, though), and the compiler can easily determine if it is a line or not.

It does not take much for a program to determine if such a small graph is cyclic or not, or if it is a line or not, which is what the compiler does. So the compiler does not go into an infinite loop, and the JVM never runs out of stack space since 1) neither the compiler runs on the JVM, nor 2) the JVM get to executes (since nothing gets to compile and the compiler never invokes under such conditions the JVM anyways.)

I'm not aware of any languages that permit such cyclic inheritance graphs (but I've been doing nothing but Java for 11 years, so my memory of anything other than Java is mushy.) I cannot see, furthermore, the use of such a construct (in modeling or real life). Might be theoretically interesting, though.

**edit**

Ok, I ran your code and indeed it causes an stack overflow. You were right. I'm gonna have to sit and really study this to understand why the compiler allows such a construct.

**Nice find!!!!**

Comment: Thanks... I was just sitting here tooling around trying to break stuff, and it broke

Comment: @luis.espinal, There is nothing special about the program. The stack overflow is due to the two mutually recursive constructors. See my answer.

Comment: i figured it out... caught me off guard at first... still, i can't believe it lets you make such a blatant and obvious circular reference

Comment: @aioobe - no, no, I know that there the two constructors are mutually recursive (nice answer btw.) The thing I have to ponder is why the compiler would let such construct exist. There shouldn't be a reason (on a valid model) for an inheritance chain to be cyclic or for inner members to extend their containing types. It is really not good modeling, questionable semantics. I'm surprised the compiler allows it at all. Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: The semantics is clear: It is an infinite recursion, which would run for ever on a machine with infinite memory. Actually, if the compiler or JVM was smart enough, it would compile it into `while (true) {}` which has an equivalent semantics. As you probably realize, there is just as little reason to *forbid* this Java program, as it would be to forbid a `while(true) {}`-program.

Comment: I highly doubt that the compiler will take the step of converting mutually recursive functions into an infinite loop with an empty body. Unlike the later (whose detection is decidable), mutually recursive functions might or might not have a stop condition (the detection of which is undecidable in anything but the most trivial cases.) It is a good point, however, why the compiler would not forbid such constructs. Having said that, smart IDEs do flag for cyclic inheritance conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted could get problematic if we change it a bit more:

```
public class Outside {

    public class Inside extends Outside {

            public Inside(int val) {
        }

    }

    private Inside i;

    public Outside() {
        i = new Inside();
    }
}
```

But this is not really related to the fact that `Inside` is an inner class of `Outside`, it could have happened with separate top-level-classes identically.

Comment: Here is [a real-life example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916020/stackoverflow-confusion) where someone build something with this problem.

Comment: I'll say that such an example is caused by bad design. I cannot fathom a **valid** OO model that would contemplate cyclic inheritance. Since it is not a concept that is even present in real systems, and our task is to model and build software representation of such real systems, it would follow that cyclic inheritance has no place (or should not have.)

Comment: There are some OO-languages which allow cyclic inheritance - but this then implies all classes in the cycle being synonymous. ([Cecil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cecil_(programming_language)) is an example, if I remember right.)  This still does not relate to using inheritance mixed with inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer by:

```
Class.forName("MyClass");
```

This way it gets resolved but not instantiated. So you can chack if resolution itself causes the crash.

I guess it depends on the JVM you use.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to compile :

```
class A extends A {
}
```

I get :

```
$ javac A.java
A.java:1: cyclic inheritance involving A
class A extends A {
^
1 error
```

So Java don't let you do this kind of thing. For information, `java version "1.6.0_24"`

Comment: this is not about circling inheritence(-1). It's about inner class inherits of enclosing one.

Comment: @Vladimir my answer was written before the added code to the question. Without the code, there's no way to know that the op speaks about inner classes ("you create a class that inherits itself" this is exactly what I do).

Comment: @Krtel, I would reclaim my downvote, if answer is edited once more.